# Reactjs map function - iterate json object

Tags: reactjs, iteration, map-function, react-state

I'm trying to fecth data from `db.json` dispay it in `Cards`. There are two objects in `details` array so `Cards.tsx` suppose to generate two `SimpleCard`. It's throwing `this.state.card.map is not a function` this error. Can anyone let me know where I made a mistake ?

**SimpleCard.tsx**

```js
class ShipmentCard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Card className="Card">
        <CardContent className="Card-Content">
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <h3 className="Card-Content__Title">
                title goes here
              </h3>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

export default ShipmentCard;
```

**Cards.tsx**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ShipmentCard from "../card/Card";

class Cards extends Component {
  state = {
    card: []
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/details")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        data.forEach((element: any) => {
          const shipments = element;
          this.setState({ card: shipments });
        });
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.card.map(card => (
          <ShipmentCard key={card.id} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Cards;
```

**App.tsx**

```js
const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <TopMenu />
      <Cards />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

**db.json**

```js
{
  "details": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "Heromisha",
      "services": [
        {
          "type": "customs"
        }
      ],
      "total": "1000",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "userId": "E222"
    },
    {
      "id": "456",
      "name": "Honda",
      "services": [
        {
          "type": "customs"
        },
        {
          "type": "insurance",
          "value": "100"
        }
      ],
      "total": "3000",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "userId": "E111"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` seems to be the array of cards.

Try replacing

```
      .then(data => {
        data.forEach((element: any) => {
          const shipments = element;
          this.setState({ card: shipments });
        });
      });
```

by

```
      .then(data => this.setState({card: data}));
```

By the way, `card` seems like a strange name for the state, maybe `cards` would be more accurate.

Comment: Noted that. Working good. How I missed that. Thanks @Matthieu